# Sorting through association using acts-as-taggable-on gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I am trying to dynamically sort a table of `Posts` by `:type` using [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem.

Let's say my Post object has 3 columns: user, title and date. I can easily sort a table of Post by putting in my controller `@entries = Post.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).page(params[:page])`

`sort_column` and `sort_direction` being referred as:

```
def sort_column
  Post.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "published_at"
end

def sort_direction
  %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "desc"
end
```

However, Post can also have a **type** attached to it. In my Post model, I have:

```
acts_as_taggable
acts_as_taggable_on :types
```

and in the table of my view I simply display the tag by writing:

*views/posts/_posts.html.slim*

```
...
td.tags = entry.type_list.first.titleize unless entry.type_list.blank?
...
```

Is there an easy way to **alphabetically sort the table by type**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `acts-as-taggable-on` gem adds polymorphic association.  You can take full advantage of Active record.

You have to do something like this. This will give your `post` in `alphabetical` order.

```
Post.includes(:taggings).joins(:types).order("tags.name")
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Ah, a simple Rails association... why didn't I think of that earlier... it did the trick! Cheers mate.

Comment: whats up ? whats the problem ?

Comment: @Sirlate, he might be waiting for some more answer. Actually, fiirst he accepted the answer and then unaccepted it. Strange.

Comment: @all Thanks, don't worry about your score/bounty/cookies,you will get them all ;)